# Color reduction merging adjacent color classes having close centers

Tags: algorithm, colors, merge, grouping

I want to know if there is any known algorithm which can do this.

To obtain the final color classes, a merging procedure is applied. According to this procedure, adjacent color classes having very close centers are merged. Assuming that the final color cluster centers should not be closer than a given distance, we employ a simple merging procedure where points with color distance smaller than h are considered to belong to the same color cluster. Thus they are merged and their mean value represents the final color value which will be assigned to the cluster.

Comment: What are colour centres?

Comment: the center is the mean value of a cluster's color

Comment: And how do you mean a colour? What colourspace are you using? How do you add colours? None of this is at all obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for an [agglomerative hierarchical clustering method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering), but you should clarify the definition of color metric first.